# Ransack Gem Rails and multiselect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, jquery-chosen, ransack

I am using the ransack gem for my rails app and have a problem with multiselect.
I have a job and a company model, a company has many jobs, a job belongs to a company. 
I want to perform a search on jobs so people can see jobs from specific companies, 
I have done some research and apparently this should work in the search form:

```
= search_form_for @q do |f|
  = f.collection_select :company_name_cont, Company.all, :id, :name, {:multiple => true}, class: 'chosen-it'
  = f.submit "search"
```

So in the view I get the list (with autocomplete from the chosen gem) but when I click on search it returns no result and I can't select multiple companies.

However, when I use a search field instead like this:

```
= f.search_field :company_name_cont
```

The search works.

Could you help me guys

Thanks a lot

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `company_name_in` instead of `company_name_cont`:

`= f.collection_select :company_name_in, Company.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}`

More info can be found in ransack's wiki here: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#in

Comment: insert an empty {}, before the multiple option and it works!

Answer (score 1):

In general, we can write this as

```
= f.collection_select :some_id_in, Model.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true}
```

where some_id is a model attribute for which we have multiple select value for filter.